# How can I change the resolution of the GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution, 18.10

I'd like to change my GRUB's resolution since it seems as if it doesn't use my screen's whole 1920x1080. I tried to get the supported resolutions using `videoinfo`, but it literally shows nothing. I tried `vbeinfo` as well, but that didn't work either.

Looking forward to a solution for this or at least a way to tell which resolution GRUB is actually using at the moment.

This is how my GRUB config file looks:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=8
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

Comment: You may achieve what you want by editing GRUB_GFXMODE but I advice against it.

Comment: Unless you plan on using a magnifying glass to read your GRUB menu, I'd recommend setting GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480.

Comment: Can anyone explain why Grub2 does not scale properly out of the box? Another one to file in the “Linux isn’t hard” folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the default look of my grub menu when the some of the content in `/etc/default/grub` file is

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480
```

[image]

When i edited the file and changed some of the content in `/etc/default/grub` like below

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480
```

and run `sudo update-grub` it looks like this

[image]

when content is like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=960X600
```

It looks like this after running `sudo update-grub`

[image]

The value 960x600 i choose from below

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

Comment: That actually did the trick for me. Although the exact resolution itself doesnt seems to make a whole lot of a difference, but a change in ratio is quite noticeable.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: Hi @BhikkhuSubhutu.. What did you try.. Can you explain..

Comment: It worked on the second reboot (after an update). Not sure why by it is all good.  Thanks

Comment: I think i remember why it worked on the second try.. I did not see the line (commented) that you showed.. and then added it myself (without the comment).  Then later I went back to be sure I did not copy the text with the  comment.  (that was fine).  Then I tried checking the screen res support from xrandr.. that was fine.  Then I noticed the same line with a comment   (GRUB_GFXMODE=640X480) a few lines below.. I uncommmented it and that seemed to work.. I am secretly using Elementary OS.. and maybe a different grub file?  I doubt it.. but I think that is why it worked "after the update"

Answer (score 5):

You can use 1920x1080 screen size but you will want to generate a larger font. Although the following GIF uses grub themes for additional graphics, generating larger 24 or 36 point fonts is the same for regular grub.

[image: Grub Boot]

---

### Make Grub fonts

Even if you are just using regular grub, if you want a different font you must use `grub-mkfont` program first. The same holds true for Grub Customizer used by OP and Grub Themes used in first section of this answer.

Here are the fonts I have made for grub to use:

```
$ ll /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/*.pf2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 176923 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/dejavu_14.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  20041 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_17.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  23339 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  31498 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_26.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  15244 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_regular_12.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  19148 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_regular_17.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 113623 Jul 11 17:05 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_bold_italic_36.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  45391 Jul 11 17:08 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_light_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  41020 Jul 11 17:16 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_18.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  46423 Jul 11 17:16 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  68602 Jul 11 16:59 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_28.pf2*
```

To create a font use the `grub-mkfont` program like this guide outlines: [Increase Font in GRUB for High DPI Screens](http://blog.wxm.be/2014/08/29/increase-font-in-grub-for-high-dpi.html):

```
sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2 \
  --size=24 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

Then in your `/etc/default/grub` configuration file tell it to use the new `.pf2` font file:

```
# More readable font on high dpi screen, generated with
# sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2 \
#    --size=24 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2
```

Finally run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: So simple, this ought to be the preferred answer. My surface book 2 has 3240x2160 resolution on a 15" screen and the default grub font is barely legible without a magnifying glass. It's literally laughably small, as in my coworkers laugh at it. Following these directions for font size 48 gives me a grub screen with fonts nice and large.