# Is it possible to set higher grub screen resolution then max videoinfo value?

Tags: grub2

The maximum value that is present on `videoinfo` grub command output is `1280x1024`

What can I do to increase this value?
Does it depend on the video card/driver I use, or its a motherboard limitation?

I would like to set it to the native screen resolution(2440x1080), but it seems it's not possible if I don't have its in `videoinfo`?

Comment: can you go through this https://askubuntu.com/q/1091778/739431

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it from the bios settings. You go to BIOS setup then under boot up configuration select switchable graphics instead of discrete graphics.